# Are there any good Jungian studies of Irish myth ( not generic 'Celtic')?

Tags: irish, symbolism

This kind of stuff is what I am interested in: [Myths of Irishness: The Fomorian Connection](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25484361?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Articles would be ideally the best.

Comment: I believe we're talking about [archetypal literary criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archetypal_literary_criticism).

Comment: I'm familiar with archetypal criticism and the books on that bibliography. But I'm not  of any archetypal criticism of irish myth. The short answer for 'why Jungian' is that I'm interested in this approach.  A slightly longer answer is that I think a Jungian approach to archetypes one of the best attempts at mapping out innate patterns (instincts) we have by virtue of being human . I see mythology as working  those archetypes in pictorial form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and for reminding me of the Maedbh & addiction one. I'd seen it but haven't read it. It's the kind of material I'm after.   I"m familiar with Emma Jung, also Von Franz etc, but they usually deal with a generically 'celtic' and usually the the Brythonic material as filtered through the middle ages. While we have analogues, cauldrons of plenty etc here in Ireland the grail myth isn't a big Irish theme.